# Story about the first person to be resurrected

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story that takes place in the future in which the leading scientist brings his father back to life as the first "test" of resurrection technology. His father was chosen based on his optimism about the future, and the son said that everyone else was watching to see how someone would react to the news that they had died and were brought back to life. The implication was that technology had advanced quite far, and people from the past would be shocked to see the world as it truly is, so the father was shown a "fake" world designed to look like what he was used to so that he could be eased into reality. From what I remember of the story, it takes place entirely as a conversation between the father and son.

I feel like this story was written by a fairly famous author, but I cannot be sure.

Can anyone help me find this story?

Comment: This is probably the play asked about here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176127/web-published-play-in-a-world-where-all-humans-have-been-brought-back-to-life Is it possible it was a play script?

Comment: Yes, that sounds exactly like the one I am looking for. Too bad no one has answered it, and interesting coincidence that this was posted 5 days ago.

Comment: I've added some of your information (and some more of my own) to my question. @DavidStone, would you like to close this one as a duplicate of that?

Comment: I would, but it looks like I cannot mark this as a duplicate until your question has an upvoted or accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Resurrection - By Harry Stottle

I read this many years ago and for some reason it has stuck with me. I came across your post while searching for the original story.

http://www.fullmoon.nu/Resurrection/PrimarySpecies.html

Seems to have been written by a Harry Stottle who also calls himself the Ragged Trousered Philosopher.

The first part, linked above is titled Primary Species.

- *...scientist brings his father back to life as the first "test" of resurrection technology.*

  > Those who died between your death and the Informed Consent Protocol will remain dead until their nearest and dearest decide how and when and whether to resurrect them,” says Stuart. “We predict that, eventually, at least 35% of all the humans who ever lived will, at some stage, be resurrected.
- *...the father was shown a "fake" world designed to look like what he was used to so that he could be eased into reality.*

  > I’ve set up this simulation to mirror your bedroom and the farmhouse exactly as you remember them. But that’s only to make it easier for you to assimilate what has happened to you,” explains Stuart. “The information which constitutes “You”, exists on a giant network. You have no precise physical location. Even the processors which implement your thought processes are running in many places simultaneously.

Comment: Could you possibly provide some more details in your post which match the points made in the OP, links tend to die, and as long as this site is alive, the info will then be here.

Comment: Nope. I provided the authors name, the pen name the author uses and a link to a site the author has maintained for the last ~20 years. I think that is enough

Comment: Really? You're unwilling to put in a little bit of effort to show evidence of why this story should be the same? You realise links die, sometimes the author stops maintaining the site, yet you've made no mention of the story that the OP is looking for, or what in the story suggests any form of similarity.

Comment: -1 from me also. You need to explain *why* this is the story, not just dump a link and make people go look for themselves

Comment: I don't 'need' to explain anything. I signed up for this site for the sole reason of providing the OP with the answer to the question he asked.

Comment: There's an example of a better laid out answer.